# Bridging DSL wifi router to a PacketCable modem

Tags: configuration, router, internet, wifi, modem

I used to use a DSL based Internet connection (an AirLive WT-2000ARM). Recently I changed my Internet connection and it is now provided through *PacketCable*. The provider gave a modem for it (Thomson THG570), it has one Ethernet output and works fine. But I would like to take advantage of the wifi router I have.

*How can I make the wifi router route through the PacketCable modem?* What direction should I move? Sorry, for the possibly dummy question, I tried to figure out how to configure these devices, with no luck yet.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the WAN port of the router to the Ethernet port of the modem. The connect your other devices to either the router's wifi or one of its switch ports.